# Silverlight Isolated Storage Settings Being Overwritten by Another Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0, isolatedstorage

I have a Silverlight application deployed on both our staging and production servers. This application caches information using isolated storage settings.  If I browser to

http://stagingserver/pagewithsilverlight.aspx

everything works fine, data is stored to isolated storage on my machine just fine. However if I browse to

http://productionserver/pagewithsilverlight.aspx

everything works EXCEPT that nothing is saved to isolated storage on my machine.  Both pages contain copies of the same xap file.  Why would it behave one way when hosted on one server and behave a different way when hosted on a  different server?

<strike>Edit: Additional note, I have verified that data is not being saved to isolated storage by looking at the C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Silverlight\is directory while running my application.</strike>

Edit #2: After further investigation (process monitor), the data is being written to isolated storage, but then being overwritten by another SilverLight application on the same page. This didn't show up on our staging environment since the second application was not deployed there. Somehow, both applications are being given the same isolated storage location.  They are unique xap files, so how are they being given the same IsolatedStorage.ApplicationSettings location?

Comment: what are the versions of the following namespaces on each of these servers?

using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

Comment: @CodeToGlory:  Namespaces don't have versions.  Besides that, what version any dll has on the server has no bearing on what the XAP does on the client.

Comment: I can't think of any reason what there would be a difference.  Hence I would be testing my assumptions.  The XAPs are really the same? The code in the xap to save stuff to isolated storage is really running?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones.  The xap files are binary duplicates of one another. It was just a copy and paste.  I later went and added server logging call to the production version.  It is definitely hitting the call to save stuff to isolated storage. Within that same routine, I can even even read the settings back out of Isolated storage and log those as well.

Comment: @Jacob: just to be clear,  you noticed that the isolated storage isn't working because when you re-visit the XAP the application doesn't behave as expected based on data it thinks it has stored successfully but instead behaves as if its the first time being vistied?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your applications are using `GetUserStoreForSite()` instead of `GetUserStoreForApplication()` on the `IsolatedStorageFile` class?